# Looping through every value

Tags: stata

I was trying to run a loop through a variable and was unsure how to code up my thoughts. So, I have variable called `newid` that goes as

```
newid
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

and so on.

```
foreach x in newid2 {
    replace switchers = 1 if doc[_n] != doc[_n+1]
}
```

I want to modify this code so that this code will run for each two values (in this case run for 1 and 1, 2 and 2). What would be the best way to modify this? Please help me

Comment: Actually, your goal is not very clear to me. Could you elaborate your data example, and provide the desired output?

Comment: See e..g  http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/try-all-values-with-foreach/index.html for a general answer. For your specific question, and often, the answer may be that no explicit loop is needed at all.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this can be done with `levelsof`:

```
clear
input id str1 doc
1 "A"
1 "B"
2 "A"
3 "C"
3 "A"
end

gen switcher1 = 0

levelsof id

foreach i in `r(levels)' {
    quietly tab doc if id==`i'
    replace switcher1 = 1 if r(r)>1 & id==`i'
}
```

However, you there are certainly [more efficient ways](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0029) to accomplish your goal. Here's one example that tags ids that switch doctors:

```
ssc install egenmore
bysort id: egen num_docs = nvals(doc)
generate switcher2 = cond(num_docs>1,1,0)
```

The underlying idea is the same. You count the number of distinct values of doc for each id. If that number exceeds one, the id is tagged as a switcher. The second version is arguably more efficient since it does not involve looping over each value of id.

Comment: The last example can also be done by `bysort id (doc) : gen switcher2 = doc[1] != doc[_N}`